# Docker Container's Memory Swappiness value outside of documented range

Tags: docker

When I do `docker inspect`I read that

```
Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS
Docker version 17.05.0-ce, build 89658be
# GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="cgroup_enable=memory swapaccount=1"
"MemorySwappiness": -1,
```

or

```
Ubuntu 17.10
Docker version 17.09.0-ce, build afdb6d4
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
"MemorySwappiness": null,
```

However [the Documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#swappiness-constraint) states that it is a value between 0 and 100.
The second example might result from Swapping being disabled on the docker host.

- Am I missing some paragraph of documentation?
- Are these undocumented values cast to 0? Or 100?

Comment: Probably because your kernel doesn't support memory swap and memory limit ("By default, if you do not set --memory-swappiness, the value is inherited from the host machine.") - https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/resource_constraints/#--memory-swappiness-details

Comment: Probably. But how can I inherit a value of `-1` if valid values range `from 0 to 100` The value appears to be undocumented or I appear to fail at reading :-)

Comment: Apparently -1 is the default value, docker engine somehow also treats null as -1.
Docker is made by human, you can open a git issue to ask them to better document this part.

Comment: Sorry forgot [the link](https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/2459)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`-1` is a deprecated value. As you can see in this issue `0` is the new `-1`

https://github.com/moby/moby/pull/33898